# Iterate through unconnected severs without providing package error SSIS

Tags: sql-server, foreach, error-handling, ssis, script-task

Created a package that will loop through all the servers in our environment. Package consist of a Foreach loop and within it is a Script Task connected to a Data Flow task and an Execute SQL Task. The purpose of the Script Task is to verify server connection.If the server connects then the package uses Precedent Constraints to continues through the Data Flow. If it doesn't connect, the package uses Precedent Constraints to continue through an Execute SQL Task. The problem that I have encountered is that when the loop finds a server that it cannot connect to, it gives the package a failure error. The loop continues which is good but I do not want a Data Flow failure or package failure to occur. I've attempted to use a try catch block in my Script Task but it doesn't seem to work the way that I want it to. Set DatabaseCanConnect as a False Boolean variable. Used as the ReadWriteVariable. Set strToServer as my connection string variable. Used as the ReadOnlyVariable. I used the code below for my Script Task.

```
public void Main()         {
string connString = Dts.Variables["User::strToServer"].Value.ToString();
string String = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=" + connString.ToString() + ";Trusted_Connection = yes;";

            try
            {
                using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection())
                {
                    connection.ConnectionString = String;
                    connection.Open();
                }
                Dts.Variables["User::DatabaseCanConnect"].Value = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Dts.Variables["User::DatabaseCanConnect"].Value = false;
            }

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

Comment: " it doesn't seem to work the way that I want it to."   How does it work, and how do you want it to work?

Comment: I would like for it to verify all the connections and if it encounters a server that it cannot connect to, I do not want it to provide an error to the package. I want it to just move on to the next server. Right now, if it encounters a server that it cannot connect to, it sets off package level errors then continues on to the next server

Comment: The Script task sets off an error?   It doesn't look like it should with the code you've posted.  What is the exact error message?

Comment: I actually believe it is the Data Flow that is failing due to a "CannotAcquireConnection" error. Maybe its my Precedent Constraints that might be causing the issue? I flipped the constraints and the package did not return errors just like I wanted. But for some reason, now the data flow task does not populate the table for the connected servers

Comment: Add a screenshot of your precedence constraints.

Comment: Probably easier to type it out. The first constraint is an Expression and Constraint for Success value. Expression :@[User::DatabaseCanConnect]==false. It leads to the data flow. The second constraint is and Expression and Constraint for Success value. Expression: @[User::DatabaseCanConnect]==true. This leads to the Execute SQL Task that sends a notification that the server cannot connect

Comment: Seems to me you want the opposite.   If DatabaseCanConnect==true, you want to go to the Dataflow, and if it's false you want to send the email.

Comment: That actually sets all the iterations to go to the Execute SQL Task. The Data Flow Task doesn't even get a green check mark of completion when the package is ran

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the Execute SQL Task and look at the value of the variable when it breaks.  Is it getting set to False when it shouldn't be?